# cannot install scikit-fda python package for functional data analysis

Tags: python, installation, functional-programming, analysis

that's my first question, I'm not able to install the scikit-fda package of python because it gave me the following error:
can someone help me about this? thanks in advance

**Failed to build fdasrsf
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fdasrsf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe your problem is related with https://github.com/jdtuck/fdasrsf_python/issues/20. Try using the workarounds in that issue.

Comment: thank you for the help, I just work out the reason of the error, it is because I'm using a recent version of python, for this package is required python 3.6 or 3.7.